# Order DIV's by Value Username Value within

Tags: jquery

I have the following DOM Structure. Each 'contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberContainerDIV' shows a member photo, name etc.

I need to be able to re-order these ContainerDIV's by the H2 Username A to Z.

So the below would need to move the 'contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberContainerDIV' pieces of DOM so it's ordered Adam, Bob, Eric. Note: I need to move the whole piece of DOM for each user.

```
<div id="contactsBodyMainContainerDIV">

 <div class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberContainerDIV">
  <div class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberWrapperDIV">
   <h2 class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberUserNameH2">Eric</h2>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberContainerDIV">
  <div class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberWrapperDIV">
   <h2 class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberUserNameH2">Adam</h2>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberContainerDIV">
  <div class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberWrapperDIV">
   <h2 class="contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberUserNameH2">Bob</h2>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

I'm unsure how to do this.

Note: it need this function as members will be added on the fly.

Any advise on how to achieve this?

Comment: do you get this contents from a database? Is a jQuery solution the only option?

Comment: You could place the content in a table which goes inside a div / multiple divs and look into tablesorter plugin: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this code helps

```
var sorted = $('.contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberContainerDIV').sort(function(a,b){
    return $(a).find('.contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberUserNameH2').text() < $(b).find('.contactsBodyMainDisplayMemberUserNameH2').text()) ? 1 : -1;
});

$('. contactsBodyMainContainerDIV').html(sorted);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create an option list, which then is easy to sort:

markup:

```
<ul id="my_list">
    <option value="Eric">Eric</option>
    <option value="Adam">Adam</option>
    <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$("#my_list").html($("#my_list option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
}))
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRA5b/1/

note: you can obviously stuff all your div's into that `<option>` tags: check here: http://jsfiddle.net/zRA5b/2/

edit: you can also sort by option value (which might come in handy if you want to sort by some other database value, like age or lastname, etc.) using:

```
$("#my_list").html($("#my_list option").sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value== b.value? 0 : a.value< b.value? -1 : 1
}))
```